# How to get the non-packed solidityKeccak hash in Python Web3

Tags: web3js, web3.py, keccak, sha3

For

```
Web3.solidityKeccak(['bool'], [True])
```

, Python Web3 yields: `0x5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2`

This matches the output of `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(true))` in Solidity. However, I want the output of `keccak256(abi.encode(true))` because my contract has to deal with variably-sized data structures.

In Web3 JS, I could get the correct output (`0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`) using:

```
web3.utils.soliditySha3(web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['bool'], [true]))
```

How do I get it from Python Web3?

Of course I don't need the hash of a boolean. This just serves as an example for easy verification that the correct encoding was used.

Comment: The word `However` makes your entire question unclear, since the expression before it and the expression after it are identical.

Comment: `In Web3 JS, I could get the correct output` - correct according to what (i.e., what scenario other than "web3.js" does this output represent)?

Comment: @goodvibration It is the scenario of normal ABI encoding (as opposed to packed ABI encoding). That's also the difference in the Solidity expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out how it can be done: There is a python library for Solidity ABI encoding and we can abuse the fact that compact ABI encoding of bytes is the identity.

The library can be installed with:

```
pip install eth_abi
```

Its documentation is found here: https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

After importing the library via

```
import eth_abi
```

, the hash can be computed as follows:

```
abiEncoded = eth_abi.encode_abi(['bytes', 'bytes32'], [input1, input2])
hash = w3.solidityKeccak(['bytes'], ['0x' + abiEncoded.hex()])
```